# Random Forest Regressor Feature Importance all zero

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm running a random forest regressor using scikit learn, but all the predictions end up being the same.
I realized that when I fit the data, all the feature importance are zero which is probably why all the predictions are the same.
This is the code that I'm using:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import pandas as pd

merged_df = pd.read_csv("/home/jovyan/efs/vliu/combined_data.csv")

target = merged_df["400kmDensity"]
merged_df.drop("400kmDensity", axis = 1, inplace = True)

features_list = list(merged_df.columns)

#Set training and testing groups
train_features, test_features, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(merged_df, target, random_state = 16)

#Train model
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 150, random_state = 16)
ran = rf.fit(train_features, train_target)

print("Feature importances: ", rf.feature_importances_)
#Make predictions and calculate error
predictions = ran.predict(test_features)
print("Predictions: ", predictions)
```

Here's a link to the data file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ECgKAH82wxIvt2OCv4W5ir1te_Vr3N_r/view?usp=sharing

If anybody can see what I did wrong before fitting the data that would result in the feature importances all being zero, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, you take `merged_df[target_variable]` off of the dataframe, then you do `merged_df.dropna(axis = 0, how = "any", inplace = True)`, potentially breaking the link between feature and label if the indices are changed. Interestingly, this should throw an error in train_test_split like `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples`, so you may have gotten lucky and not actually dropped anything. Beyond that, have you checked a scoring metric to check your model performance? If your model predicts all the same class, then no feature would be important, for example

Comment: Yes, the dropna I added after as a precautionary measure because I've already cleaned all the data so that there are none in a previous function. So I can get rid of that. When I run it, the score is a really small number, 1.78e-06, which I assume is because the predicted values are all the same. Since this is a regressor there are no classes, but even so, the numeric predictions are all the same value.

Comment: Same root cause: If there is no variation in the predicted values, there can be no importance to any of your features. As to why _that_ is, unfortunately that's outside the scope of what we can tell from the provided information

Comment: When I check the feature importances, I check it right after I call the rf.fit function. That is when it shows all zeros, even before I predict anything, and I think that's what is causing the predicted values to all be the same. So I guess it's the same problem, that I can't figure out what is going wrong in the random forest regressor fit function

Comment: Yes, same root cause for both issues. Most likely it's an issue with the input data, not the `fit`, given that the `fit` method is right out of the box and unmodified (at least in the code you've shown) and works for many applications

Comment: Like G. Anderson hinted to already: Can you elaborate on what the data looks like (also the target that you choose)? A minimal example would be nice in order to see if the issue is connected to this.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the post to a minimum working example along with the data. I'm currently using Scikit learn version 1.1.1 which doesn't work with this code although it did work using version 0.24.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your variables "400kmDensity" and "410kmDensity" share a correlation coefficient of >0.99:

```
np.corrcoef(merged_df["400kmDensity"], merged_df["410kmDensity"])
```

This practically means that you can predict "400kmDensity" almost exclusively with "410kmDensity".  On a scatter plot they form an almost perfect line:

[image: Scatterplot of the variables "400kmDensity" and "410kmDensity"]

In order to actually explore what affects the values of "400kmDensity", you should exclude "410kmDensity" as a regressor (an explanatory variable). The feature importance can help to identify explanatory variables afterward.
Note that feature importance may not be a perfect metric to determine actual feature importance. Maybe you want to take a look into other available methods like *Boruta Algorithm*/*Permutation Importance*/...

In regard to the initial question: I'm not really sure why, but RandomForestRegressor seems to have a problem with your very low target variable(?). I was able to get feature importances after I scaled *train_target* and *train_features* in rf.fit(). **However, this should not actually be necessary at all in order to apply Random Forest!** You maybe want to take a look into the respective documentation or extend your search in this direction. Hope this serves as a hint.

```
fitted.rf = rf.fit(scale(train_features), scale(train_target))
```

As mentioned before, the feature importances after this change unsurprisingly look like this:

[image]

Also, the column "second" holds only the value zero, which does not explain anything! Your first step should be always EDA (Explanatory Data Analysis) to get a feeling for the data, like checking correlations between columns or generating histograms in order to explore data distributions [...].

There is much more to it, but I hope this gives you a leg-up!